# Determine if a functor has right/left adjoint

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, hom-functor

> In $Set$ category let $P_X$ a functor defined as follows: given a set $Y$, $P_X(Y)=X\times Y$ and a function $f: Y \to Z $, $P_X(f)= 1_X \times f$. Determine if $P_X$ has left/right adjoint.

At first glance, since I'm still a novice in category theory, I was thinking that this exercise was very hard, now I would like to understand if I have found a possible solution.

For left adjunction we need the existence of a functor $G : Set \to Set$ such that
$$Hom_{Set}(P_X(Y), Z) \simeq Hom_{Set}(Y, G(Z))$$
And since we know that exist a natural isomorphism $Z^{X\times Y} \simeq (Z^X)^Y$, the $G$ functor that we need is $G = Hom_{Set}(X,-)$.

For right adjunction I was thinking to use the universal propriety of product, but i still don't know how to formalize it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: assume the left adjoint $F$ exists and write the adjunction for the terminal object $1$.

Comment: @КряжевАрсений do you mean writing the adjunction using unity and counity? Beacuse otherwise I'm not very sure on what i should write.

Comment: No, I meant a bijection on Hom-sets.

Comment: Admitting the existence of F and so: $Hom_{Set}(F(Y),Z) \simeq Hom_{Set}(Y, P_X(Z))$, but when Y is the terminal object 1 (which if I'm not mistaken in $Set$ is the singleton), F of the terminal remains the terminal (I think...) and the bijection holds when $Z$ and $Z\times X$ has the same cardinality. Could work? @КряжевАрсений

Comment: They don't often have the same cardinality for all $Z$, do they? (I meant to suppose $Z=1$, not $Y$, but this also works as you've just shown).

Comment: now i see and I think it's related to the "diagonal map" mentioned below. The resume it's that $P_X$ is left adjoint to the $Hom_{Set}(X,-)$ functor and has a left adjoint (so it's right adjoint) when X is empty set or a singleton. @КряжевАрсений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, you are showing that $P_X$ is a left adjoint (that is, that it has a right adjoint).

For the other direction, keep in mind that a right adjoint must preserve limits. Does $P_X$ preserve limits?

Edit to clarify:

Let's suppose that $P_X$ is a right adjoint. Then it preserves limits; in particular, it preserves products. Consider a specified one-element set $1 = \{w\}$. Then consider that $1 = 1 \times 1$ in the obvious way, with $1_1$ being the projection maps $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$.

Pushing this diagram through the functor $P_X$, we see that $X \times 1$ must be the product of $X \times 1$ with itself, where the projection morphisms are the identity. That is, we see that $(X \times 1, 1_{X \times 1}, 1_{X \times 1})$ is the product of $X \times 1$ with itself.

Then using the canonical isomorphism between $X \times 1$ and $X$, we see that $(X, 1_X, 1_X)$ must be the product of $X$ with itself.

Then consider the canonical product $X \times X$. Note that the induced map from $X$ to $X \times X$ using the maps $\pi_i = 1_X : X \to X$ is $(1_X, 1_X) : X \to X \times X$. Since $(X, 1_X, 1_X)$ is a product of $X$ and $X$, this means the map $(1_X, 1_X)$ must be an isomorphism.

That $(1_X, 1_X) : X \to X \times X$ is an isomorphism is equivalent to any two elements of $X$ being equal.

But in fact, we can do even better by considering that $P_X$ would have to preserve the terminal object. For if $P_X$ preserves the terminal object, then we can pick a canonical 1-element set $1 = \{w\}$. Then we see that $P_X(1) = X \times 1$ must be isomorphic to $1$. Then $X \simeq X \times 1 \simeq 1$.

So if $P_X$ has a left adjoint, then $X$ is a one-element set. And conversely, it's easy to show that if $X$ is a one-element set, then $P_X$ has a left adjoint (in fact, if $X$ is a one-element set then $P_X$ is an equivalence of categories, which is even stronger than having both adjoints).

Comment: I'm not trying to be formal but just to understand intuitively, when we say that some functor preserve something it means that what "happens to the pre-image happens to the image". If what I'm saying is correct I think that $P_X$ is right adjoint iff the set $X$ is isomorphic to $X\times X$ and we have several cases when this happens

Comment: @GodelSpassky You're almost correct, but not quite. In fact, $P_X$ is a right adjoint if and only if the "diagonal map" $(1_X, 1_X) : X \to X \times X$ is an isomorphism. This is because preserving limits means preserving all parts of the limit diagram - so preserving $F$ products means that if $(A, p_1, p_2)$ is a product of $B$ and $C$, then $(F(A), F(p_1), F(p_2))$ is a product of $F(B)$ and $F(C)$. And the diagonal map is an isomorphism iff any two elements of $X$ are equal (in classical logic, iff $X$ is either empty or has exactly 1 element).

Comment: I found your point view very interesting but I'm struggling to fully understand it. The last part is clear both the part of preserving products and the fact that diagonal map is an isomorphism iff $X$ is empty or singleton. What I'm not finding is the connection between these two.

Comment: @GodelSpassky I misspoke earlier. I meant to say that if $P_X$ is a right adjoint, then the diagonal map is an isomorphism. In fact, $P_X$ is a right adjoint iff $X$ is a one-element set.